# Splitting a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got this data frame with data from IMDb in it.  One of the columns has the movie title with the year attached in parentheses.  Looks like this:

```
The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
```

What I really want is to have the title and year separate.  I've tried a couple of different things (split, strsplit), but I've had no success.  I try to split on the first parentheses, but the two split functions don't seem to like non-character arguments.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Try `strsplit(as.character(v1), '\\s*\\(|\\)')[[1]]` where `v1 <-  'The Shawshank Redemption (1994)'`  I used `as.character` as I suspect your column might be `factor` class.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here's how to create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include what you've already tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: @akrun, could you please post your answer and explain it?

Comment: Don't know if @akrun's solution works if there are parenthesis in the movie title

Comment: @nicola In that case, we may use `strsplit(as.character(d1$v1), '\\s*\\((?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])\\)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]`

Comment: @akrun can you explain the ?<=[0-9] portion of your solution? (as compared to ?=[0-9])

Comment: @AndrewTaylor It is a lookaround to match the `)` preceded by a number or a parentheses `(` followed by a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
t(sapply(strsplit(c("The Shawshank Redemption (1994)"), '\\s*\\(|\\)'),rbind))
```

The above code will work if you just pass in the column of your data frame containing the title.

Answer (score 7):

The `strsplit` works on `character` columns.  So, if the column is `factor` class, we need to convert it to `character` class (`as.character(..)`).  Here, I matching zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by parenetheses (`\\(`) or `|` the closing parentheses (`\\)`) to `split`

```
strsplit(as.character(d1$v1), '\\s*\\(|\\)')[[1]]
#[1] "The Shawshank Redemption" "1994"
```

Or we can place the parentheses inside `[]` so that we don't have to escape `\\` (as commented by @Avinash Raj)

```
strsplit(as.character(d1$v1), '\\s*[()]')[[1]]
```

#### data

```
v1 <- 'The Shawshank Redemption (1994)'
d1 <- data.frame(v1)
```

Comment: This worked, but returned a data.frame with two rows containing the titles and years instead of two columns.  Still worked, though!

Comment: @milk May be you need `do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(d1$v1), '\\s*[()]'))`  I used `[[1]]` because there was only a single element.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do an exact splitting (ie, splitting on the brcakets which exists at the last), you may try this.

```
x <- c("The Shawshank Redemption (1994)", "Kung(fu) Pa (23) nda (2010)")
strsplit(as.character(x), "\\s*\\((?=\\d+\\)$)|\\)$", perl=T)
# [[1]]
# [1] "The Shawshank Redemption" "1994"                    

# [[2]]
# [1] "Kung(fu) Pa (23) nda" "2010"
```

Answer (score 2):

`tidyr` solution

```
df%>%separate(col,c("name", "year"), "[()]")
```

Thanks to Avinash, I can take his regular expression and apply in `tidyr`

```
m<-c("The Shawshank Redemption (1994)","The Shawshank (Redemption) (1994)", "Kung(fu) Pa (23) nda (2010)")
m2<-data.frame(m)
m2%>%separate(m,c("name", "year"), "\\s*\\((?=\\d+\\)$)|\\)$")

                        name year
1   The Shawshank Redemption 1994
2 The Shawshank (Redemption) 1994
3       Kung(fu) Pa (23) nda 2010
```

Comment: I got an "Invalid column specification" when I tried this.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: in which code, do you have `df` dataframe with `col` column?